# Access OBDC Connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I setup a new user with a new computer and installed MS Office. When I open the link to the Access DB I get the error

> OBDC - connection to SQL Server Native Client 11.0Path/of/Accessdb

The SQL Server is on a local server. We pass the windows ID as server authentication.

Unfortunately I did not develop the Access DB and have no documentation on how to configure it from the developer

SQL Server is the backend and MS Access is the front. The question is how can I get this instance of Access to connect to the SQL Server database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481086/sql-server-backend-and-access-frontend-odbc-connection-to-sql-server-native-cl

Comment: You're going to need to get into the application and see exactly how it is trying to connect to the SQL Server. One possibility is that it relies on an ODBC DSN to make the connection and the DSN has not been created on the new machine. In any case you'll need to [edit] your question and provide more information, otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thank you Gord. I have also read the the DSN could cause this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by installing the ODBC Native Client 11.0 driver