# What is causing this bizarre error message when opening my Access database on another PC?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, connection-string

The error is following: [image]

The ODBC connection string is obviously wrong and not in the right format.  But I don't understand where Access is getting it from!  The correct and working connection string (string saved in the Access database via the Linked Table Manager) is below. It should be noted that my colleague is opening the compiled .accde file in Access Runtime and does not have Office installed on his computer. The data tables are in SQL Server.  Another colleague, who does have Office installed (presumably) got it to open with no problem.

This is the **proper** connection string which is used in Linked Table Manager to link the tables to SQL Server:

```
"DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=hgws19.win.hostgator.com;UID=*******;PWD=********;Trusted_Connection=No;APP=Microsoft Office;DATABASE=mypubid_usergamelog;"
```

What I can't understand is why this **other** string in the error message is being used instead of the **correct one** in Linked Table manager. Anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have a look at [SQL Server backend and Access frontend - ODBC Connection to SQL Server native client failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481086/sql-server-backend-and-access-frontend-odbc-connection-to-sql-server-native-cl)

Comment: Maybe the 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' is missing on that one station? Can he see/ping the server?

Comment: You maybe have defined another object that does not appear in the Linked Table Manager... like a Pass-Through Query.

Comment: Indeed I do have a pass-through query that was added just before this mess happened. I did so because I needed to pull data from a view. I tried copying the LTM connection string into the ODBC Connect Str property of the pass-through query and it gave me an error message that it was not formed properly. It wants me to create a machine or file DSN but then that won't work when copied to another computer will it?